# ServiceStack JsonServiceClient send basic instead of Basic for Authorization header

Tags: authorization, servicestack

I am using the JsonServiceClient client to talk to a RESTful service hosted on IIS 7 by an external vendor.

Here is some sample code I am using to call their Get method.

```
ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.JsonServiceClient client = new ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.JsonServiceClient("UrlToVendor"));

client.SetCredentials("userName", "password");

client.AlwaysSendBasicAuthHeader = true; 
DTOReturn result = client.Get<DTOReturn>(string.Empty);
```

I always get an authorization failure. We put a sniffer and the Authorization header is being sent as:

> basic userName:password

instead of

> Basic userName:password

We were able to use standard .Net calls to get it to work

```
System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(
                "UrlToVendor");

string authInfo = "userName:password";
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));

req.Accept = "application/json"; //text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
req.Method = "GET";
req.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Basic {0}", authInfo);

System.Net.HttpWebResponse res = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

And these standard calls failed the same as the JasonServiceClient if we changed "Basic" to "basic".
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like someone had the same problem. This recent commit changed the auth-scheme from "basic" to "Basic". https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/d4f21c5355ab87d7315e142372eef9a40e096b5f
You should be able to just update your dlls.

According to RFC 2617 sec 1.2 the **auth-scheme is case-insensitive**.
See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#page-47. I would be curious as to why the vendor service won't accept it.

Comment: Great. I will pull and test again. Thanks for pointing that out. I tried to search Githud to find the code that was setting it but couldn't find it.

Comment: I am already running ServiceStack-v3.9.32 that was uploaded 3 months ago. The fix was put in a month ago. When will a new package be uploaded? I would prefer to be using packaged releases versus me having to build a patch to get it working.

Comment: Don't know about releases, you would have to talk to @mythz

Comment: I pulled the v3.9.37 dll's using NuGet and that fixed the problem.